# WebStorm - Hitting return/enter in "search everywhere" (double-shift) doesn't open the selected file

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm, and hitting double-shift opens the Search Everywhere box. I can search for the file I want, and click on it to open it. I love using the keyboard for everything, though, but when hitting Enter/Return, the box closes but the file is not opened.

See this GIF for illustration:

[image: Searching and hitting enter: no result.]

I've mapped "Enter" to "Enter" in the settings box, so I think it should work. I haven't touched a lot of other settings, either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to [IDEA-200654](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200654); it's fixed in 2018.3 (fix is not yet included in any released build).

Enabling `new.search.everywhere` in **Help | Find Action, Experimental Features** dialog (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpbAA.png) may help